# Publishing single event to multiple topics using Kafka Streams

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

How can i produce single event to multiple topics in Kafka streaming dynamically?

I came across **TopicNameExtractor** but it returns only 1 topic at a time.

Is there any other way where I can produce single event to multiple topics in kafka streams or can I create a hybrid version by combining **KafkaStreams** and **KafkaTemplate** for producing events?

Comment: Please see the answer provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77648527/2070861

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by dynamically. In Kafka Streams you can, for example, separate a stream into several branches that will go to different topics based on a predicate over the input record:

```
Map<String, KStream<String, Long>> branches =
    stream.split(Named.as("Branch-"))
        .branch((key, value) -> key.startsWith("A"),  /* first predicate  */
             Branched.as("A"))
        .branch((key, value) -> key.startsWith("B"),  /* second predicate */
             Branched.as("B"))
.defaultBranch(Branched.as("C"))
```

See https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html