# Routing same event to multiple kafka topics dynamically

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

I have a requirement in which I have to route a kafka stream to multiple topics based on some condition evaluation.I came across TopicNameExtractor interface but it only supports single topic.Is there a way to produce event to multiple topics.

Tried topicNameExtactor interface but it returns single topic to send to

Comment: I cannot close this question as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77644133/publishing-single-event-to-multiple-topics-using-kafka-streams because that one does not have answers. But that's exactly where we are with this one.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you are using the Kafka Streams library or the standard Java client (producer/consumer).

If you are using Kafka Streams, have you looked into the branching feature in Kafka Streams? https://kafka.apache.org/28/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/BranchedKStream.html
This may be different from the use case that you are referring to. But, if you want to split your data stream into multiple topics based on a condition, then branching would help you.

You can also manually use a `KafkaTemplate` to send to multiple topics programmatically. Keep in mind, though, when you are doing this if you are using Kafka Streams, this breaks the end-to-end processing guarantees from Kafka Streams. However, this is a viable strategy that you can consider.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I am using kafka streams.I have looked into branching strategy and it will split the stream into branches based on some predicate evaluation.But in my case I want to send the same stream to multiple topics

Comment: In that case, you may want to manually send them to multiple topics via `KafkaTemplate`.  Have you seen this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388525/streaming-messages-to-multiple-topics